# Using an image as menu : animation inside div

Tags: html, css, image, drop-down-menu, animated

I am looking to **animate an image as a menu.**
When **hovering** some part of the image , **a menu list appears.**
I'm a newbie coder so I'm a bit lost in the process i must use (image mapping, sprites, js...).

Here is the work I'm trying to achieve :

## JSFiddle

[Menu Equipiece](https://jsfiddle.net/B4b4j1/0e3bba63/)
 
However, the menu does not appears hovering the wheels.

I made a previous test where it is working :

## JSFiddle

[Test](https://jsfiddle.net/B4b4j1/jxhy32y6/)

## CSS

```
.roue{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
margin-top:-200px;
margin-left:265px;
transition:all 0.5s ease;}
```

Comment: what is the issue and what is the goal? isn't clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `div#menu` inside the `div#roue` and it'll work. I made an update on the fiddle and you could see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0e3bba63/2/).

```
<div class="roue">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.equipiece.com/userfiles/www.equipiece.com/images/Remorque-roue.png?ts=1450481525803" alt="roue de remorque" width="90" height="90">
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="list">
            <li><a href="http://www.equipiece.com/cat-roues-85_0-87_0_0_0.htm">Roue complète</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jantes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pneus</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I feel little shameful It was that simple (((

However, last request... how can put the text of the menu list on one line ?
I made the padding wider but it the text doesn't adapt ?
Thx

Comment: Ah found it this time.. seems " white-space: nowrap;" is doing the job !